# Using bootstrap 3.0 modals to load dynamic, remote content within an iframe

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried several of the suggestions posted here on other questions and on stackexchange, and nothing is working to my satisfaction.

I am trying to load dynamic content into a modal. Specifically, YouTube videos or Soundcloud audio within an iFrame. So that any user who visits the site, can enter links for videos or audio. The modal then dynamically loads that users links. Each subsequent user can see each others links, all within a modal. (separate modal loads up for each user)

I can't get this to work quite right. I have created a separate html file called "modal.html" to test this out, which includes an iframe with the proper YouTube/Soundcloud clip.

I've also tried including an iframe, within class modal-body, as suggested by one user, and then have that iFrame load a second html page (modal.html) which in turn also has an iframe to load a youtube player or soundcloud player.  But an iframe loading a page with another iframe seems inelegant and caused other html/css problems I had to address.

I am also confused about whether i need to use "data-remote=" inside my tag, or does the href suffice? Or do I use the data-remote inside the first of the modal. Or Both, or either? Neither has worked.

Here's my code:

```
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="modal.html" data-target="#myModal">Click me</a>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-remote="modal.html" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 3):

What is the exact nature of the problem you are experiencing?

I would probably use the jQuery .load() method to insert the content from modal.html into the modal and then open the modal. So something like this:

```
$(function() {

    // intiliaze the modal but don't show it yet
    $("#myModal").modal('hide');

    $('a[data-target="#myModal"]').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var myModal = $('#myModal').
            modalBody = myModal.find('.modal-body');
        // load content into modal
        modalBody.load('/modal.html');
        // display modal
        myModal.modal('show');
    });

});
```

UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO OP'S QUESTION:
Another way to do it would be to simply put an iframe inside .modal-body and set the source of the iframe to "/modal.html".

Comment: The exact nature of the problem is that the modal appears but is empty with no content.  Is there any way to achieve this without special jQuery?  The docs and other examples here seem to indicate this should be do-able using stock Bootstrap methods via HTML and CSS.

Comment: Try putting an iframe inside .modal-body and set the source of the iframe to "/modal.html." That might work. The problem with the way you're doing it now is that the href attribute of the link is used to tell Bootstrap which modal to open, not where to get the content from to populate the modal.